# Can't use PrimeFaces with Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, primefaces, pom.xml

I added PrimeFaces to my pom.xml dependencies and in my project there is the jar file primefaces-4.0.jar.

Then I created a simple xhtml file with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <p:spinner />
</body>

</html>
```

After deploying and calling the jsf file in my browser, I just get an simple input field, that has nothing to do with PrimeFaces. There are no error messages in my Eclipse console.

Can somebody help me? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `<body>` with `<h:body>`. Also, `<h:head>` should be used instead of `<head>`.

Refer to [PrimeFaces Getting Started](http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted) page.

Answer (score 2):

For maven configure:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml configure

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error, only when i cutted off the dependency by maven and inserted the jar i could see the correct rendering of the primefaces tags.

Comment: In a directory under classpath

Comment: That is what maven does for you. So if it does not work like that find the cause of that problem. This is at most a temporary workaround

Comment: sure, but i was doing just a little try with primefaces and this issue, apparently related to maven, was very strange..