# PrimeFaces 5.1 not being included properly

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, wildfly

I'm trying to leverage PrimeFaces 5.1 in my JSF application.  The app is deployed as an EAR file, with 1 WAR module and multiple EJB modules.  The entire thing is built using Maven, and deployed on Wildfly 8.1.

I've included the PrimeFaces dependency in my root-level pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>${version.primefaces}</version>
            </dependency>
```

...and in my WAR pom.xml, I've declared it as a dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

When I build the EAR using Maven, I can see that the primefaces-5.1.jar file is included, as expected, under my WAR module in `/WEB-INF/lib`.  That much seems to be working.

My JSF page has a simple `<p:messages />` tag in it, with a JSF FacesMessage set via an action class.  However, when I visit the page itself I do not see the `<p:messages />` component rendered.  Instead, if I view the source I ***actually see*** `"<p:messages ... />"`.  That is, I see the JSF source for that tag, rather than the rendered component.

I am declaring PrimeFaces in my JSF file like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
...
```

...and when I view the source of the rendered JSF page, I see the text `"<html xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">"`.

It seems to me that the PrimeFaces rendered is not being initialized or called properly.  I've followed the directions on the PrimeFaces site that indicate how to get started with the library, but either my project structure is wrong or I am missing a step.

Any idea why my PrimeFaces JSF library is not being included and used properly?

**EDIT:**  My web.xml declaration of the Faces Servlet looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
...
```

Comment: In your page, do you use `<body>` or `<h:body>`?

Comment: And faces servlet in `web.xml`? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26969937/4074715) has an example.

Comment: Updated the question to show the snippet of my web.xml where I declare the Faces Servlet

Comment: What is the url you are testing? If you replace `*.xhtml` with `*.jsf` in `web.xml` and change your url to `http://<context_root>/<your_page>.jsf`, does that work?

Comment: Nope.  Same behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue in how Eclipse was deploying my project's EAR file to the app server.  The WAR project wasn't set to include the Maven dependencies in the deployment assembly.  Once I made that change it deployed as expected and Primefaces worked without issue.